# Check if a point is inside a rectangle (not knowing the coordinates, but knowing distances to vertices)

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, rectangles

I have to solve  the following problem:
I have 4 points (A, B, C, D) which form a rectangle, but I do not know their coordinates. I have another point (X), I do not know its coordinates either, but I know the distances between point X and all other 4 points (XA, XB, XC, XD). I need to be able to tell if X lies within a rectangle formed by A, B, C, D.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you at least know the side lengths of the rectangle?

Comment: No, just the distances.

Comment: Is it true that the rectangle _must_ be ABCD (not any order, right)?  I think this plays a role in determining the answer.

Comment: @Jared The order might matter if you asked *'does there exist a rectangle for given set/sequence of distances?'* However OP assumes the rectangle exists, and then the problem is undecidable: there exist both a rectangle containing X and a rectangle with X outside (except when X is the center of a rectangle)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems it is impossible to know whether X is inside for sure. For example, if we had a rectangle ABCD and a point X inside of it, WLOG so that the vertical distance from X to CD is less than the vertical distance from X to AB, creating a new rectangle ABEF with EF parallel to AB and CD, but EF underneath X with the same vertical distance creates a new rectangle with exactly the same distances to the vertices, but with X outside.

(Low picture quality, which is why I hesitate to put a picture. But I also thought that my above explanation was sort of unclear, so I posted this too.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the picture is very helpful. Would it help add another check to eliminate ABEF - the angles (AXB, BXC, CXD, ...) must be less than 180 degrees?

Comment: Yes, if we knew the angles were all less than 180 degrees then we could conclude that X is inside the rectangle. This can be confirmed because you'd know the angles AXB, BXC, etc. have X as the interior angle of triangles AXB, BXC, etc. so that you could conclude that they were inside the rectangle. However, if an angle was greater than 180 degrees (such as EXF) then X is the exterior angle of EXF and that therefore X is not inside ABEF.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible in general:

```
A . . . . . D . . A'
.           .     .
.           .     .
B . . . . . C . . B'
```

Let $X$ be the centre of $ABA'B'$.  Then $XA=XA'$ and $XB=XB'$, and of course $XC=XC$ and $XD=XD$.  But for suitable choice of $C$ and $D$, $X$ is inside $ABCD$ but not $A'B'CD$.

Answer (score 1):

For any point $X$ inside the rectangle, except the rectangle's center, there exists another rectangle, which has the same vertices-to-X distances, but does not contain $X$. You can construct it by mirroring one of the rectangle's edges by an axis parallel to the edge and passing through $X$.

The opposite is also true: you can make a reverse construction for the $X$ outside a rectangle to find an appropriate rectangle containing $X$. If $X$ lies 'opposite to some edge', not to a corner, that is, when $X$ lies between two parallel lines containing two opposite sides of a rectangle, one side mirroring will suffice. If $X$ is 'opposite to a corner', that is it lies in the angle vertical to the rectangle's corner (see https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vertical_angles.svg), one needs two such mirrorings for two adjacent sides of the rectangle.

As a result,

- if three of the four $AX$, $BX$, $CX$, $DX$ distances are equal, then $X$ is a center of the $ABCD$ rectangle (and the fourth distance must be equal to those three, too), so you know it is inside.
- In any other case you can't tell whether $X$ is inside or outsde the rectangle, because there exist two rectangles $ABCD$, $A'B'C'D'$ with the same distances of their respective vertices to the given point: $AX=A'X$, $BX=B'X$, $CX=C'X$, $DX=D'X$, one rectangle containing $X$ and the other one missing it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the four given points are as given as four trees in a landscape forming a nondegenerate rectangle. If your question could not be decided this would mean that we have four different circles intersecting in at least two different points $P$, $Q$. But this would imply that the four circles all have their center on the median $m$ of $P$ and $Q$, contrary to assumption.

Comment: The point is the trees are not given, just distances to them. Imagine you are a bat wih one ear only (no stereo hearing allowing the bearing measurement, just distances). Are you between the trees or outside?